# ZeroMQ ZMQ$Socket.nativeInit()

Tags: java, sockets, netbeans, zeromq

i created a simple example to test zeromq but i have a exception after running example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ZMQ.Context context = ZMQ.context(1);
    ZMQ.Socket socket = context.socket(ZMQ.PUB);
    socket.bind("tcp://*:8888");
    while (true) {
      String s = System.console().readLine();
      if (s == null) break;
      socket.send(s);
    }
    socket.close();
    context.term();
}
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.zeromq.ZMQ$Socket.nativeInit()V
    at org.zeromq.ZMQ$Socket.nativeInit(Native Method)
    at org.zeromq.ZMQ$Socket.<clinit>(ZMQ.java:435)
    at org.zeromq.ZMQ$Context.socket(ZMQ.java:365)
    at clienteadministracao.ClienteAdministracao.main(ClienteAdministracao.java:10)
```

any suggestion ? my IDE is netbeans and i use ubuntu

Comment: It looks as if there's a native library (`.so` or `.dll`) missing.

Comment: http://zeromq.org/bindings:java

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're using Java binding to native library, either make sure that the .so library file (or .dll for win) is there or use JeroMQ - complete java implementation of zeromq, see here: [jeromq](https://github.com/zeromq/jeromq)